# How to allow access to controller method for either authenticated user or authorized user?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

How to allow access to the controller method for either authenticated user or authorized user?

```
    [Authorize(Roles='admin')]
    public void Post(Employee emp){
    
    }

    [Authorize]
    public void Get(int empid){
    
    }

    public void Patch(Employee emp){
    
    }
```

In the above code, post method is accessible by admin role and get method is accessible by authenticated user without any role.

I need to allow access to Patch method for either

1. user with admin role
2. authenticated user without any role

Comment: Doesn't `Authorize` without a `Roles` parameter meet that requirement?

Comment: `Authorize` with no parameters, uses the default policy, which doesn't check roles at all. Do you want to prevent users with other roles?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the Authorize attribute for the Patch method, both the user with admin role and authenticated user without any role could all access the patch method.

If you don't set any policy or role for the Authorize attribute, it means it will let any user who has authenticated to access this method. The user who has authenticated will include the user which has already authenticated and has the admin role.